How can I get a batch script to keep an Msys2 terminal open?
I'm trying to write a batch file that will automate opening all of the MinGW64 terminal windows I plan to open and cd into an appropriate directory. My work PC uses Windows 11.
Right now, I'm using this command to get something running:
start "" C:\msys64\mingw64.exe "cd repos"

However, while this does cause a mingw64 terminal to appear and what I presume cd into the repos folder, that terminal immediately closes instead of staying active. If I append a call to vim after the cd command, it stays active as expected but closes when I quit vim.
I've found the following 2 questions that appear to be related to what I'm trying, but the presented solutions don't work for me:

Uses the start command
Uses the cmd script provided by msys2

Both of these still have the same result of immediately closing the window.
How can I make a batch script that creates a MinGW64 terminal window and keeps it active after it's done executing any provided commands?
EDIT: Again, I'm not asking how to run a command in the MinGW64 terminal from the batch script. I'm asking how to keep that terminal ACTIVE when it would otherwise wait for user input? I'm trying to stop the process from killing the terminal after the supplied command(s) is(are) finished executing and instead wait for me to kill the terminal manually. As if it were at the state of a blinking cursor waiting for user input.

You may also find the answers to this question interesting

@Compo So, after trying one of the solutions in the link you provided I have this command: C:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -mintty -mingw64 -where "<snip to my cd location>" -c "vim". This still works the same as what I have in the question and still has the same problem. It executed the command as expected, but the terminal dies when I decide to quit vim instead of waiting for me to kill the terminal manually.

Have you tried, @Start "" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K "C:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -mintty -mingw64 -where "<snip to my cd location>" -c "vim"" or possibly @Start "" /D "P:\arent\OfRepos" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K "C:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -mintty -mingw64 -where "repos" -c "vim"".

I'm curious why you need this. I understand wanting to open just bash at a specific directory (-where ... without -c ... solves that), but why would one want to open some other executable and keep bash running after it quits?

@HolyBlackCat Because I have some saved sessions in vim that I don't always want to have opened on startup. Rather than open another terminal and cd into its path, a relative path from where I'm already at in 1 terminal would be quicker. Also, if I'm editing a build script or CMakeLists, I don't have to have a 2nd terminal open to just run it. A quick quit from vim and then running it would suffice. Saving a vim session shortens the command to jump back into editing if need be.

@HolyBlackCat Likewise, just having the terminal open to that location waiting for my input would be helpful instead of the terminal closing immediately because it doesn't see any more commands to execute. This one is the biggest convenience. I have 4 locations that I open to manually right now (and they just sit at the command line waiting for input) and automating that would just be easier and quicker. As described in the question, the terminal terminates after it gets to the location likely because I didn't give it any other commands.

This batch file works for me:
start /D C:\ "" C:\msys64\mingw64.exe bash -c "nano somefile; bash"

I tested it by saving it in a file named "test.bat" and then double-clicking on it in Windows Explorer.  When I terminate nano, it starts a bash shell.
